# MHL HDMI to HDMI

Tags: hdmi

I have the Roku Stick which plugs directly into an MHL port. I have a TV without MHL (just normal HDMI) that I would like to try this on.

My understanding is that I would need to introduce 5v at 500mA and then I would have a compatible port. The HDMI spec says pin 18 is powered, is this port the powered for MHL as well?

Is there a detailed pinout available for MHL HDMI?

Is there a pinout for a Micro USB to HDMI cable for the MHL spec?

Should I be asking this somewhere else?

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-Definition_Link

Comment: http://www.roku.com/streamingstick

Comment: i've done some Googleing, but don't see an off the shelf adapter, why not return the stick and get a normal roku?

Comment: Hi Corey, Thanks for your help. I bought the stick with an LED projector for $169 from an Amazon Gold Box sale the other day (http://www.amazon.com/3M-Streaming-Projector-Powered-SPR1000/dp/B008X1BV2Y). So I won't be returning it. I might, however, just go buy a normal Roku. They are pretty nice.